# Data annotation ignore case not validating on client side

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I am using the below data annotation on a property. The issue is that it is not being validated as a client-side validation. The regex is to make sure the word "unknown"(case insensitive) does not exist in the string and the string should not have digits.

It works as a server-side validation.

```
RegularExpression("!(?i:unknown)[a-zA-Z ']", ErrorMessage = "First name cannot contain digits or symbols or UNKNOWN"
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided, clearly see that you miss a part of quotation marks.

And for the regex, modify it to `[^a-zA-Z]`

That means any character that IS NOT a-z OR A-Z

Comment: space followed by quote is to allow spaces in the name. The problem I am  having with is "?i:" which is causing the validation to happen on the server side instead of client side.